# автотесты. Проверка запуска приложения

Tags: node.js, тестирование

Задача - протестировать, стартанул ли node.js сервИС.
Есть ли способ убедиться в этом, не посылая запроса?
Ответа может и не быть.

Comment: Процессы прогрепать по имени сервиса.

Comment: как вариант, спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Имеет смысл использовать что-нибудь для тестирования конфигураций.
Например, Testinfra (https://testinfra.readthedocs.io) для python.
Сможете проверить, и запущены ли сервисы, и доступны ли нужные файлы, и права, и проч.